# Microsoft Office Online App limitations

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, office365

What are the limitations to the Microsoft Office Online App (Excel, PowerPoint, Word, OneNote) when compared to the desktop version?

I'm aware that various features are un-available between the online and desktop apps, however I'm looking more towards a list of which features they might be, as well as file size limitations, amount of sheets, Columns, Row (Excel), etc.

Comment: There are not limitations.  The online applications are feature complete, if the feature supported, then its full support and has the same restrictions as all other versions of that program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are quite a few difference.  If your an advanced users you may miss quite a bit, if your a light users (don't use a lot of the advanced), the online versions probably do what you need.

That being said these are changing all the time. Your source of truth is always the service description pages for Office online components.

**Service Description for Office (compares online vs desktop features)**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office-online-service-description.aspx

More descriptive comparisons can be found here - but these may or may not be updated to keep up with the service descriptions:

**Word**

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-using-a-document-in-the-browser-and-in-Word-3E863CE3-E82C-4211-8F97-5B33C36C55F8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

**Excel**

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-Excel-F0DC28ED-B85D-4E1D-BE6D-5878005DB3B6

**PowerPoint**

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-using-a-presentation-in-the-browser-and-in-PowerPoint-8DFF31FF-3A68-4670-9915-49D51B7D3113

**OneNote**

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-using-a-notebook-in-the-browser-and-in-OneNote-A3D1FC13-AC74-456B-B391-B633A62AA83F